# Automating a FluentMigrator Rollback on Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-deployment, fluent-migrator

Currently have a release pipeline that runs my migration project in the up direction - 
e.g.

- The web app project is deployed to the environment
- In the Solution we have a fluent migrator project
- As part of the release pipeline, we run the up migrations to the latest version

All of the above works great BUT if I want to rollback the web app to an earlier version, then I need to somehow pass into the fluent migrator process the version that I want to roll back to - currently I'm not sure how I would achieve this. It's almost like I would need to know the version that was deployed in the previous release.

Currently, I rollback the web app I have to manually run fluent migrator to rollback to the version of the database I require.

Has anyone fully automated the fluent migrator rollback?

FYI My migration numbers are using the datetime as milliseconds which I get from https://currentmillis.com/

Update:

I had a plan to somehow get the latest migration in the project and use that number as a parameter to either run up to it or down to it. However, after thinking it through, the migrations that run as part of the release only know about the migrations that exist when the code in that release is built. There's no way it would know about any consequent migrations to be able to roll the database back...

I think I would somehow need to pull the latest code, build it and then run down the appropriate migration. I'm not sure this is possible. Might have to stick to a manual database roll back procedure.

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue?If Giulio's answer solve your problem,would you please accept it as the answer.This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.  If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: I'm trying the same thing but I also need to migrate up. How did manage that?
Can it be using commands (batchfile) the old way or do I need build the migration in another way?

Answer (score 0):

A less-than-elegant solution would be to append all migration identifiers to a file that is part of deployment artifacts. This way the forward migration uses the last entry, the backward migration uses the next-to-last entry.

Comment: There might be any number of new migrations in a release though so that wouldn't work. All I can think of is to somehow know the last migration number in the previous release but I don't think there would be any way to know that

Comment: if you tie the migration ids to code ids (e.g. commit hashes) than you have a (relatively) easy way of matching them.
Another way could be scanning version control history (e.g. `git log`) to find the range of identifiers.

Comment: I'm wondering if I can somehow, upon release, grab the last migration id (not sure how...? some kind of parsing of the files?), save that ID to an azure variable and then pass that in to the fluent migrator app - this way, the DB would either run up or down to that specific migration

Comment: I looked into fluentmigrator and your option might be to extend the `VersionInfo` table so it carries the ReleaseId. That would make easy to determine where rollback starts.